# Trouble using HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to HTML5. I wonder why the following code can't show a rectangle on the screen?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebServer Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var userviewcanvas = $("userViewerCanvas");
            var userviewcontext = userviewcanvas.getContext("2d");
            userviewcontext.fillRect(40, 40, 100, 100);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="userViewerCanvas" width="200" height="300">this is canvas</canvas>
    <div><span id="message"> </span> </div>
    <div><span id="stream"></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

check this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>WebServer Test</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var userviewcanvas = $("#userViewerCanvas").get(0),
        userviewcontext = userviewcanvas.getContext("2d");
        userviewcontext.fillRect(40, 40, 100, 100);
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="userViewerCanvas" width="200" height="300">this is canvas</canvas>
    <div><span id="message"> </span> </div>
    <div><span id="stream"></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the sharp sign in your jQuery selector expression and of course you need get(0) to get the plain javascript object instead of jQuery object:

```
var userviewcanvas = $("#userViewerCanvas").get(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can try and solve this problem:

**Normal jQuery**

```
var userviewcanvas = $("#userViewerCanvas").get(0);
```

**Normal Javascript**

`var userviewcanvas = document.getElementById("userViewerCanvas");`

There is a plugin that you can also make use of:

[**jCanvas**](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/)